# Why is the bottom half of the circuit shortcircuited?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

A follow up to [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/698536/understanding-a-short-solution-to-a-diode-exercise), regarding this circuit:

[image]

Below \$V_1\$ applies a rectangular wave of amplitude \$24V\$. For this post I'm only concerned in the case \$V_1 = -24V\$. In that case, according to the teacher, the bottom half of the circuit is short-circuited i.e. need not be taken into account. **Why is this the case?**

Comment: Do you understand what a diode does? Does it conduct if there is -24V over it?

Comment: why would V1 go down to -24 V?

Comment: @jsotola does it not cycle between \$24V\$ and \$-24V\$?

Comment: does R3 connect to R5 or is that ink bleed?

Comment: @Justme it doesn't, as the voltage needs to be larger than the threshold voltage of the diode (in this case \$0.6V\$). However, how do we know any of the diode have \$-24V\$ over them? Only thing I can see is that the node connected to the top of the voltage source has a voltage of \$-24V\$ with respect to ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For charge to flow there must be a closed path around the voltage source V1.  If V1 is negative D1 is reversed biased so can be removed for the sake of analysis. So the circuit can be redrawn as in Figure 1.

For charge to flow in the lower circuit, there must be a closd path from node A through V1, through the lower circuit to node B, then return to node A through an additional path, which does not exist.

Rx in Figure 2 is an example of an additional path from node B back to node A, **closing the circuit**.

In figure 1 Rx is infinite, thus **opening the circuit**, so there is no current in any of the elements in the lower circuit, making them irrelevent to circuit operation when V1 is negative.

> ...according to the teacher, the bottom half of the circuit is short-circuited...

The circuit is not shorted, but open.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFJmxT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> *For this post I'm only concerned in the case V1 = −24V*

With V1's upper terminal at -24 volts, the only route for current to flow is through R1.

No other current will flow.

> *the bottom half of the circuit is short-circuited i.e. need not be
> taken into account. Why is this the case?*

No, it's not short-circuited; it's actually just irrelevant when V1 = -24 volts.

Comment: I understand no current will flow through \$R_2\$ or \$D_1\$, but how do you know no other currents will flow?

Comment: It comes with experience and learning @Sam

Comment: That's...not an answer

Comment: @Sam of course I can help more but let's examine two things. (1) The question in your comment is a follow-up question based on me providing you with an answer and you producing the follow-up i.e. it is a **new** question and (2), you seem to be reluctant to accept (and upvote) answers given to any of your questions previously raised. So, ask yourself, what I might think about this situation and, how encouraged I might be to answer follow-up questions.