# Two reasonings reach the same solution, yet one must be wrong

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, resistors

Another follow-up to [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/698536/understanding-a-short-solution-to-a-diode-exercise), regarding this circuit:

[image]

Above \$V_1\$ applies a rectangular wave of amplitude \$24\ \mathrm{V}\$. For this post I'm only concerned in the case \$V_1 = -24\ \mathrm{V}\$. In that case no current flows through the diodes, so the circuit can (I think) be redrawn as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnQYnv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**The teacher's answer and my attempt.**

It is then clear that a current of \$4\ \mathrm{mA}\$ flows through \$R_1\$ clockwise. The teacher's answer for \$V_o\$ goes as follows:

> \$V_o = -6\ \mathrm{k\Omega}\cdot 4\ \mathrm{mA} = -24\ \mathrm{V}\$ [there is no further explanation].

However, I reached the same answer differently: as no current flows through \$R_2\$ (as there is no close loop the current could flow through), we may disregard \$R_2\$ altogether, getting that \$V_o\$ is equal to the voltage at the upper end of the \$V_1\$ i.e. \$-24\ \mathrm{V}\$.

**Why is my reasoning incorrect, and what exactly is the teacher's reasoning?**

While me and the teacher reached the same answer, had the value of \$R_2\$ been different (e.g. \$2\ \mathrm{k\Omega}\$), our reasonings would lead to different solutions, so one of them must be wrong.

Comment: If R2 were different Vo would still be the same since R2's current is still zero. And since your teacher's equation also ignores R2, there's no conflict or contradiction to worry over.